# Unbalanced Panel data: How to use Time Series Splits Cross-Validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, panel, cross-validation

I am currently working with a big unbalanced data set, and was wondering whether it is possible to use the Time Series Splits Cross-Validation from sklearn to split my training sample into several 'folds'. I want each fold to contain only cross-sectional observations within the timeframe of that specific fold.

As previously mentioned, I am working with an unbalanced panel data set which makes use of the multi-indexing from Pandas. Here a reproducible example to provide some more intuition:

```py
arrays = [np.array(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']),
           np.array(['2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03', '1999-12', '2000-01', 
          '2000-01', '2000-02', '1999-12', '2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03'])]

s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(11, 4), index=arrays)
```

Which then looks as follows:[image]

For instance, I would like to initially have all cross sectional units in 1999-12 as training sample and all cross sectional units in 2000-01 as validation. Next, I want all cross-sectional units in 1999-12 and 2000-01 as training, and all cross sectional units in 2000-02 as validation, and so forth. Is this possible with the TimeSeriesSplit function, or do I need to look somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TimeSeriesSplit` is a variation of `KFold` that ensures ascending index values across each successive fold. As noted in the docs:

> In each split, test indices must be higher than before... [also] note that unlike standard cross-validation methods, successive training sets are supersets of those that come before them.

[docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html)

Also remember that `KFold` and `TimeSeriesSplit` return *indices*. You already have the index that you want.

One issue is that accessing a DateTimeIndex slice in a MultiIndex is overly difficult and complicated. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806517/pandas-how-to-access-multiindex-dataframe), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175874/python-pandas-dataframe-slicing-by-date-conditions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921010/how-to-query-multiindex-index-columns-values-in-pandas). Since you're extracting the data at this point anyway, resetting the index and slicing seems acceptable. Especially since resetting the index doesn't happen in place.

Finally I recommend casting that datetime-like index to an actual datetime data type.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
arrays = [np.array(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']),
           np.array(['2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03', '1999-12', '2000-01', 
          '2000-01', '2000-02', '1999-12', '2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03'])]

# Cast as datetime
arrays[1] = pd.to_datetime(arrays[1])


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(11, 4), index=arrays)
df.index.sort_values()


folds = df.reset_index() # df still has its multindex after this

# You can tack an .iloc[:, 2:] to the end of these lines for just the values
# Use your predefined conditions to access the datetimes
fold1 = folds[folds["level_1"] <=datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)]
fold2 = folds[folds["level_1"] == datetime.datetime(2000, 2, 1)]
fold3 = folds[folds["level_1"] == datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One small question: how can I use it in combination with gridsearch, such that it chooses the 'best' parameters assessed over the 3 folds?

Comment: I suspect you'll end up doing that with the `cv` parameter for `GridSearch` and/or with `PredefinedSplit` but it seems outside the scope of the question. If you run into trouble you may want to post a new question.