# Python : get access to a column of a dataframe with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Let's say that I have this dataframe with multi index :

```
                                           Montant
IBAN                  Date       Balance
FR3724687328623865    2020-09-16 654.75      -2.00
                      2020-09-17 23.65      -88.00
                      2020-09-21 1537.00   2700.20
                      2020-09-25 8346.20   -163.21
                      2020-09-28 6247.60   -468.90
...                                            ...
FR8723498262347632    2020-10-06 13684.11  2708.00
FR9687234782365235    2020-10-16 4353.42   6311.00
                      2020-10-28 9641.23    562.78
                      2020-11-30 5436.95    -45.12
                      2020-09-30 4535.34    -43.56
```

How do we get access to the data in the columns "Balance" or "Date", I do not get why that does not work :

```
bal = df["Montant"]["Balance"]
```

or

```
bal = df.loc[("Montant", "Balance")]
```

Comment: have you read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)? It could provide the answer to your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas, how to access multiIndex dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806517/pandas-how-to-access-multiindex-dataframe)

Comment: Yeah I have read, but what I try I get a keyError on "Montant", it is why I do not get how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
In [505]: df
Out[505]: 
                                        Montant
IBAN               Date       Balance          
FR3724687328623865 2020-09-16  654.75      -2.0
2020-09-17         23.65      -88.00        NaN
2020-09-21         1537.00     2700.20      NaN
2020-09-25         8346.20    -163.21       NaN
2020-09-28         6247.60    -468.90       NaN
```

You can pass `labels` :

```
In [509]: df.index.get_level_values('Date')
Out[509]: Index(['2020-09-16', '23.65', '1537.00', '8346.20', '6247.60'], dtype='object', name='Date')

In [510]: df.index.get_level_values('Balance')
Out[510]: Float64Index([654.75, -88.0, 2700.2, -163.21, -468.9], dtype='float64', name='Balance')
```

**OR:**

Pass `indices`:

```
In [512]: df.index.get_level_values(1)
Out[512]: Index(['2020-09-16', '23.65', '1537.00', '8346.20', '6247.60'], dtype='object', name='Date')

In [513]: df.index.get_level_values(2)
Out[513]: Float64Index([654.75, -88.0, 2700.2, -163.21, -468.9], dtype='float64', name='Balance')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need indexing go to [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), and if you need your index as normal columns; do

```
df = df.reset_index()
```